# Is it still applicable to use pexpect on RedHat7 or is there alternative way to Executes a command and responds to prompts?

Tags: ansible, pexpect

I'm trying to use pexpect in Redhat7 for ansible but I wasn't able to install it. I was only getting pexpect.noarch 2.3-11.el7 @RHEL7 version. Or is there a alternative for pexpect to  Executes a command and responds to prompts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the version of the `pexpect` Python module shipped with RHEL7 is too old for Ansible (RHEL7 has pexpect 2.3, and Ansible wants 3.3 or greater). Your best option is probably to use the `shell` or `command` module to run `expect`; there is an example of this in the [documentation for the `shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#examples):

```
# You can use shell to run other executables to perform actions inline
- name: Run expect to wait for a successful PXE boot via out-of-band CIMC
  shell: |
    set timeout 300
    spawn ssh admin@{{ cimc_host }}

    expect "password:"
    send "{{ cimc_password }}\n"

    expect "\n{{ cimc_name }}"
    send "connect host\n"

    expect "pxeboot.n12"
    send "\n"

    exit 0
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
  delegate_to: localhost
```